# Timer in C# WinForms App not functioning as intended

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, timer

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 to create a Visual C# Windows Forms Application and I'm not using the Designer to setup the form.

I have what I think is a simple timer that should pause my application for a few seconds to allow a splash screen to be shown before the user can see and access the menu. But when I run debug the application doesn't appear on the screen until the timer is done and then it has jumped past the splash screen. I've looked at different ways to do timers and tried to search for help on this for hours now but cannot find a way to make it work. I'm guessing that I'm missing something very obvious but as a newbie I can't spot it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Timers;

namespace SimpleForm
{

    public class TheForm : Form
    {

        private MenuStrip menuStrip;
        private MainMenu menuMain;
        private MenuItem menuBlockFile;
        private MenuItem menuBlockOthers;
        private MenuItem menuItemExit;
        private MenuItem menuItemHints;

        static Bitmap imgIntroBg = null;
        static Bitmap imgMenuBg = null;

        private Panel pnlIntro;
        private Panel pnlMenu;

        static int counter = 1;
        static System.Timers.Timer timer;

        public TheForm()
        {

            FormInitialize();

            MenuInitialize();

            introDisplay();

            MenuDisplay(true);

        }

        private void FormInitialize()
        {

            System.Resources.ResourceManager resources = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(typeof(Game));

            this.SuspendLayout();

            this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 13);
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(714, 462);
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
            this.Name = "SimpleForm";
            this.Text = "Simple Form";
            ControlBox = false;
            BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }


        private void MenuInitialize()
        {

            this.SuspendLayout();

            this.menuStrip = new MenuStrip();
            this.menuMain = new MainMenu();
            this.menuBlockFile = new MenuItem();
            this.menuBlockOthers = new MenuItem();

            this.menuItemExit = new MenuItem();
            this.menuItemHints = new MenuItem();

            this.menuMain.MenuItems.AddRange(new MenuItem[] {
                this.menuBlockFile,
                this.menuBlockOthers});

            this.menuBlockFile.Index = 0;
            this.menuBlockFile.MenuItems.AddRange(new MenuItem[] {
                this.menuItemExit
            } );
            this.menuBlockFile.Text = "File";

            this.menuBlockOthers.Index = 1;
            this.menuBlockOthers.MenuItems.AddRange(new MenuItem[] {
                this.menuItemHints
            });
            this.menuBlockOthers.Text = "Others";

            this.menuItemExit.Index = 0;
            this.menuItemExit.Text = "Exit";
            this.menuItemExit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.menuItemExit_Click);

            this.menuItemHints.Checked = true;
            this.menuItemHints.Index = 0;
            this.menuItemHints.Text = "Temp";
            this.menuItemHints.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.menuItemExit_Click);

            this.Menu = this.menuMain;

            imgMenuBg = new Bitmap("graphics/layout/menubg.png");
            pnlMenu = new Panel();
            pnlMenu.Name = "pnlMenu";
            pnlMenu.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            pnlMenu.Width = 714;
            pnlMenu.Height = 462;
            pnlMenu.BackgroundImage = imgMenuBg;

            MenuDisplay(false);

            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        private void MenuDisplay(bool display)
        {

            this.menuBlockFile.Visible = display;
            this.menuBlockOthers.Visible = display;
            if (display == true) {
                Controls.Add(pnlMenu);
            } else {
                Controls.Remove(pnlMenu);
            }

        }

        private void introDisplay()
        {

            timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
            timer.Interval = 5*1000;
            timer.Enabled = true;

            imgIntroBg = new Bitmap("graphics/layout/Introbg.png");
            pnlIntro = new Panel();
            pnlIntro.Name = "pnlIntro";
            pnlIntro.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            pnlIntro.Width = 714;
            pnlIntro.Height = 482;
            pnlIntro.BackgroundImage = imgIntroBg;

            timer.Start();

            Controls.Add(pnlIntro);

            while (counter != 0)
            {

            }

            Controls.Remove(pnlIntro);

        }

        private static void timer_Elapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            counter = 0;
            timer.Stop();
        }

        private void menuItemExit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `while(counter != 0)` part is not the right thing to do. The `timer_Elapsed` callback will be fired when the timer is done, so you add the image (`Controls.Add(plnIntro);`) and then wait for the callback of the timer to fire. That's when its done. At that point, just remove the `plnIntro` and it should do as intended.

You don't have to lock the thread with a `while` loop for it to work.

Try to Remove:

```
while (counter != 0)
{

}

Controls.Remove(pnlIntro);
```

And put the `Controls.Remove(pnlIntro);` in the timer callback:

```
private void timer_Elapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Controls.Remove(pnlIntro);
    timer.Stop();
}
```

Comment: For me thing brings up a couple of errors on the line "Controls.Remove(pnlIntro);". One is `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Controls.get'` and the second is `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'SimpleForm.TheForm.pnlIntro'`.

Comment: Sorry, did not see that the timer_Elapsed callback was static, will fix in answer! :)

Comment: Also, the timer object do not have to be static, I would even suggest that it should not be static.

Comment: It runs but then throws an error on "Controls.Remove(pnlIntro);". Of "InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code" - "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'pnlIntro' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

Comment: Its possible that the System.Timers.Timer creates a new thread, I'm not sure about that specific class dealings. Try use a System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead and see if that helps.

Comment: With "System.Windows.Forms.Timer" it now gives the errors of `The type or namespace name 'ElapsedEventHandler' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` and `The type or namespace name 'ElapsedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Now `this.timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);` throws the error `The type or namespace name 'ElapsedEventHandler' could not be found`

Comment: The Windows.Forms.Timer is a little bit different in some parts, change the .Elapsed call to `timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Elapsed);` And the callback function declaration to  `private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e){...}`, That should do the trick.

Comment: As it's now `timer.Tick` won't I have to add a counter again as it will run that event on every tick rather than when it's finished.

Comment: "Tick" is when the timer have passed the given interval. If you want to stop it at the first run, use the timer.Stop(); call that you do.
For more info about the class, check the MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx